# certificate has expired issue by deploying docker image to Heroku from gitlab

Tags: docker, heroku, certificate, gitlab-ci, heroku-cli

I've created an app on **Heroku** and I've been able to to deploy my Spring Boot dockerized application with heroku CLI from my machine.

However, when I try to perform the same actions from **gitlab ci** I've got an error on the last command.
Everyhing before this command is working (the login to heroku, the push of the built image).

Here's my *.gitlab-ci.yml* file :

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

maven-build-application:
  stage: build
  image: maven:3-jdk-11
  script:
    - mvn clean package -DskipTests
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

docker-build-and-deploy-application:
  stage: deploy
  image: rizkimufrizal/docker-node
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - npm install -g heroku
    - heroku container:login
    - heroku container:push web --app this-is-the-name-of-my-application
   # Here is the problem
    - heroku container:release web --app this-is-the-name-of-my-application
```

Output logs from my gitlab job :

```
latest: digest: sha256:62555048c6df008140c4720fc9fa0787caf2ef547a6c9d6e2608d3ba6c6e5dfa 
size: 953Your image has been successfully pushed. You can now release it with the 
'container:release' command.
$ heroku container:release web --app this-is-the-name-of-my-application
 ▸    CERT_HAS_EXPIRED: certificate has expired
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I've made some research online but I can't find somehing on it, and I don't know what could I try ?

Maybe because the command is made inside a docker, I have to install intermediate certifcates ?

Thank you for your help

Antoine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my updated final stage to deploy on heroku :

```
docker-build-and-deploy-application:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - apk add nodejs npm
  script:
    - npm install -g heroku
    # Set the environemnet variable "HEROKU_API_KEY"
    # Get this token by running these commands :
    # #1 heroku login -i (write heroku username and password)
    # #2 heroku authorizations:create
    - heroku container:login
    # container:push web is going to build the docker image locally using the Dockerfile and push it to the repo
    - heroku container:push web --app this-is-the-name-of-my-application
    # container:release web is going to use the image pushed to deploy it
    - heroku container:release web --app this-is-the-name-of-my-application
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the node version which is used by `rizkimufrizal/docker-node` is very old with expired certificates. Try a different / updated image with a more recent version.